# Secretary problem - Riemann integral

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

I was following the derivation for the famous [secretary problem on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) and I was unsure about the step from the discrete summation to the Riemann integral. Namely, why does $\frac1n\to dt$ as $n\to\infty$? I thought $\Delta t$ was the width of the interval divided by $n$, but the width of this interval is $1-x$? Is it that the limits of $\frac{1-x}n$ and $\frac1n$ would be the same as $n\to\infty$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part of the derivation in the article alluding to a Riemann sum is hand-waving.

For a rigorous approach, write the discrete sum as

$$\tag{1}\frac{r-1}{n}\sum_{i=r}^n \frac{1}{i-1} = \frac{r-1}{n}\sum_{i=r-1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i}  = \frac{r-1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{r-1}+\sum_{i=r}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i}\right)\\ = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{r-1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} - \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} \frac{1}{i}\right) \\ = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{r-1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} - \log(n-1)- \left(\sum_{i=1}^{r-1} \frac{1}{i}- \log(r-1)\right)\right) + \frac{r-1}{n}\log \frac{n-1}{r-1}$$

We will let both $r \to \infty$ and $n \to \infty$, with $\frac{r-1}{n}= x + \phi(n)$ where $x$ is fixed and $\phi(n) \to 0$.  For example, taking $r = \lfloor 1+nx\rfloor$ we have $x - \frac{1}{n} < \frac{r-1}{n} \leqslant x$ and $\frac{r-1}{n} \to x$ as $n \to \infty$.

Substituting $x+ \phi(n)$ for $\frac{r-1}{n}$ on the RHS of (1), we get

$$\tag{2}\frac{r-1}{n}\sum_{i=r}^n \frac{1}{i-1} = \frac{1}{n} + (x+\phi(n))\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} - \log(n-1)- \left(\sum_{i=1}^{r-1} \frac{1}{i}- \log(r-1)\right)\right) + (x + \phi(n))\log \frac{1-1/n}{x+\phi(n)}$$

Using $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{i} - \log(m) = \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and taking the limit of both sides of (2) as $n \to \infty$, it follows that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{r-1}{n}\sum_{i=r}^n \frac{1}{i-1}= 0 + x(\gamma - \gamma) + x \log \frac{1}{x} = -x\log(x) = x \int_x^1 \frac{dt}{t}$$

Note that the integral is a large-$n$ approximation for the probability that the best applicant is selected from a pool of $n$ applicants when the first $x \cdot n$ applicants are rejected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer. It is definitely more rigorous. 

That said, when you say x is fixed, do you mean x is the limit of (r-1)/n as both r and n tend to infinity? 

Also terms of intuition, how can I understand why the author was able to say limit 1/n = dt?

Comment: @Morehand: In the discrete setting $r$ and $n$ are integers.  I am assuming that we specify a fixed value $x$ and for any $n$ we choose the $r$ such that$(r-1)/n$ is as close to $x$ as possible -- and $(r-1)/n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$.  That is $r$ is the closest integer to $1+nx$.

Comment: To make $\int_x^1 \frac{dt}{t}$ appear in $P(x)$  as $n \to \infty$ you need to arrive at a Riemann sum like $\frac{1-x}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{x + (1-x)j/n}$ somewhere in the manipulation of the original discrete sum.  I don't think it is possible to do this precisely for arbitrary $x$ when you start with $\sum_{i= r}^n \frac{1}{i-1}$.  Nevertheless the Riemann sum associates $\frac{1-x}{n}$ with $dt$. Why do you think the author has anything rigorous in mind here?

Comment: Rigour aside, how would the author even know its highly plausible? I saw similar derivations when searching online and each of them equated the limit of 1/n as n tends to infinity with dt, eg https://thebryanhernandezgame.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/secretary-problem.pdf

Comment: It is plausible because if $r-1 \approx nx$, the sum is approximately $$x \left(\frac{1}{nx} + \frac{1}{nx+1} + \ldots  +\frac{1}{nx + (n-1 - nx)}\right) = x \left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x+1/n} + \ldots  +\frac{1}{x + (n-1)/n  - x)}\right)\frac{1}{n} $$ which looks a bit like a Riemann sum for $\int_x^1 \frac{dt}{t}$.

Comment: Could you please provide more details to help me understand the step from the penultimate line to the last line? Thank you

Comment: @Morehand: I assume you are asking how the limits of the terms on the RHS of (2) are computed to reach the final result.  Clearly the first term $1/n \to 0$.  Since $\log(\cdot)$ is continuous and $\phi(n) \to 0$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log \frac{1-1/n}{x + \phi(n)} = \log \frac{1-0}{x + 0} = \log \frac{1}{x} = - \log(x)$.

Comment: The middle term in parentheses is the difference of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} - \log(n-1)$ which converges as $n-1 \to \infty$ to $\gamma$ -- the well-known result I mentioned -- and  $\sum_{i=1}^{r-1} \frac{1}{i} - \log(r-1)$ which also converges to $\gamma$ since $r-1 \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  The difference consequently converges to $\gamma - \gamma = 0$.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I was referring to the steps in your prior comment to mine, ie I don’t see how the sum in brackets is approximated by the integral described because I don’t see where the  width of partition term appears.

Comment: @Morehead: That comment was not meant to be a rigorous derivation -- it is just speculation on how the author may have found a Riemann sum to be "plausible" as you said.

Answer (score 0):

RRL very kindly provided a rigorous derivation and answered some of my follow up questions. Thank you.

I’ve also realised what I was missing re: the Riemann sum - when introducing 1/t = N/i, the summation increments are no longer 1 but 1/N. This is consistent with delta t in a Riemann sum, hence 1/N outside the brackets becomes dt as n tends to infinity.